# Python list comprehension with a function as the output and the conditional

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Given some function that can return None or another value and a list of values:

```
def fn(x):
    if x == 4:
        return None
    else return x

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

*I want to have a list of the outputs of `fn()` that don't return None*

I have some code that works which looks like so:

```
output = []
for i in lst:
    result = fn(i)
    if result:
        output.append(result)
```

I can express this as a list comprehension like so:

```
output = [fn(i) for i in lst if fn(i)]
```

but it runs `fn(i)` for anything that doesn't return `None` twice which is not desirable if `fn` is an expensive function.

Is there any way to have have the nice pythonic comprehension without running the function twice?

a possible solution:

```
output = [fn(i) for i in lst]
output = [o for o in f if o]
```

Comment: You know what's Pythonic? Your for-loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that `None` is produced by the function, not the thing you are iterating over. Try

```
 output = [fi for fi in map(fn, lst) if fi is not None]
```

Comment: This is essentially the answer I was looking for, a way to iterate over the results of the function. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just combine your solutions:

```
[x for x in [fn(i) for i in lst] if x is not None]
```

The downside is that any `None`s in the original list *not* produced by `fn` will be removed as well.

Comment: The comparison with None should be changed to `x is not None`.